# Find the roots of a quadratic equation, with integer coefficients, rounded to nearest integer

Tags: roots, arithmetic, quadratics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In a Python geometric algorithm I am developing I need the roots of a quadratic equation, with integer coefficients, rounded to the nearest integer; n.5 must be rounded upward. I need an exact result, not some approximation. (The reason is that these roots are used in if/else statements, and if the result is not exact the wrong path is chosen, and the algorithm fails catastrophically.) The calculation is performed millions of times, therefore speed is important.

In Python I have at my disposal integers of unlimited size, an integer division rounded downward to the nearest integer, and an isqrt(n) function that returns the square root rounded downward to the nearest integer.

I find no practical solution. Can someone help me?

To avoid misunderstanding, the result must always be exact.

Comment: Could you please give an example or two (and include the most general form of an equation you'll need to solve)?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist. The general for of the equation is
a.x^2 + b.x + c = 0, with a, b, and c integer.  
An example is:
12345.x^2 + 78901.x +23456 = 0
I need the solutions, rounded exactly to the nearest integer, with n.5 rounded upward.
By preference an efficient method, as the integers are quite large, easily 50 digits, and millions of equations must be solver.
I have at my disposal isrt(n), with n integer, which returns the floor of the square root of the integer n, or the root rounded down. I also have m//n, with m and n integer, which returns the division rounded down.

Comment: 1) By how much of a factor you would like to beat the naive algorithm in terms of performance?
2) Are there any bounds or constraints on $a,b,c$ (e. g. all are positive, or $|c|>|a|$)?
3) How are the coefficients obtained (for example, all three are outputs of a PRNG modulo a large prime)?
4) Have you considered using a separate library (such as GMP) instead of Python that generally underperforms in such tasks, sometimes by a few orders of magnitude?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist. My prime concern is to have an exact result, performance is secondary. 
The coefficients are the result of geometric intersection calculations, I am not aware of any constraints. 
I did not consider GMP as my impression is that Python big integers have decent performance, and in Python one can simply write expressions in mathematical notation. And GMP does not bring me an exact result.
But again, my requirement is an exact result.  I now use the following:
(((-b + sign.sqrt(b**2 - 4.a.c))//a) + 1)//2
This is pretty accurate, but not exact, as far as I know.